# objects in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

hi i want to know how to create objects in both javascript and jquery.

something like this.

```
Person = new Person();
Person.name = "John Doe";
Person.age = "16";
```

It is possible? Any help will do. Thank you

## update #follow-up

If i'm able to create an object using javascript can i pass the object i recently created to a ajax request in jquery?

Comment: Why would you want to specify the age as a string?

Comment: oh. it is just an example. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery is made using (or is) JavaScript, you can do this to work in both:

```
function Person(){
  this.name = '';
  this.age = 0;
}

Person = new Person();
Person.name = "John Doe";
Person.age = "16";

console.log(Person.name); // John Doe
console.log(Person.age);  // 16
```

---

You can pass arguments to constructor function as well:

```
function Person(name, age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
```

And add methods inside constructor or `prototype` too (I prefer latter):

```
function Person(name, age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;

  this.getName = function(){
     console.log(this.name);
  };

  this.getAge = function(){
     console.log(this.age);
  };

}
```

Or better using `prototype`:

```
Person.prototype.getName = function(){
   console.log(this.name);
};

Person.prototype.getAge = function(){
   console.log(this.age);
};
```

Now you can create as many instances as you want:

```
var person1 = new Person();
var person2 = new Person();
person1.name = "John Doe";
person1.age = "16";    
person2.name = "Michael John";
person2.age = "25";    
person1.getName();
person1.getAge();
person2.getName();
person2.getAge();
```

**Result:**

```
John Doe
16
Michael John
25
```

---

**Good Practices:**

- Always capitalize the first letter of constructor function (as in `Person`) so that people could know that it has to be instantiated with `new` keyword.
- Generally/mostly it is good idea to add methods via `prototype` property (as shown above).

Comment: If i'm able to create an object using javascript can i pass the object i recently created to a ajax request in jquery?

Comment: @Dreyfus15: Yes you can do that. If you know how to use that passed object then fine otherwise that sounds a different question you can ask eg *how to use passed objects in ajax request* :)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. But not recommended. Look at [this link](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) which explains the what, the how and the why.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is just a Javascript library. jQuery doesn't have any objects in itself, you use the objects in Javascript. (jQuery does however have a few methods that can be useful for dealing with objects, like the `extend` method.)

You need a constructor function to use the `new` keyword. It's basically just a regular function:

```
function Person() {
}
```

Now you can create the object exactly as in your code.

---

You can also set the properties in the constructor:

```
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
```

Usage:

```
var person = new Person("John Doe", "16");
```

---

The constructor function has a `prototype` object that you can attach methods to:

```
Person.prototype.getFirstName = function() {
  return this.name.split(' ')[0];
};
```

Now you can use those methods on any object that you create with that function:

```
var person = new Person("John Doe", "16");
var firstName = person.getFirstName();
```

---

If you just need one object, for example to pass on some data, you can create it using the literal object syntax:

```
var person = { name: "John Doe", age: "16" };
```

---

#### Update:

Yes, you can create an object any way you like and pass it on to a jQuery method:

```
$.get(url, new Person("John Doe", "16"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var person = {
  name: "John Doe",
  age: 16
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as how you would do in Java

```
Car model=new Car();
model.number="21EX";
model.name="Mazda 21";
```

You could also create your own class in JavaScript as follows:-

```
 function People(){
//private properties
var _name = '';
var _age  = 0;

//private method
function doSomeThing(){}


//public method
this.setName = function(name){
    doSomeThing();
    _name = name;
};

 this.setAge = function(age){
    _age = age
 };
}

People person=new People();
 person.setName("John Doe");
 person.setAge(33);
```

[Here](http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS.html) is a quick example of the OOP JavasScript principles and how to use them.
I also recommended reading about [closures](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/closures-in-javascript/)